# Google AdBot is causing an exception on visit that I can't track down

Tags: exception, mobile, bots, unhandled

I have a mobile site that has a smart-phone version and a non smart-phone version and my issue is on the non smart-phone version.  The version in question is built using the mobile framework so that it is more accessible.  The only time I see problems with the site is when Google Adbot hits it every hour or so.  It throws Uncaught exceptions from System.Web but there is nothing in the stack trace to tell me what is happening.  I have wrapped every method on the page and in the one control that is on the page in a try/catch block and none of them are being triggered.

Comment: <hanging head in shame>  found the problem.  Connection pool was set WAY too low.  We have many Google probes due to high amount of paid search and when Google slammed the site it simply used up all the connections and shut it down.  This was the first mobile site that really was hit by Google like this so we hadn't seen it before.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Connection pool was set WAY too low. We have many Google probes due to high amount of paid search and when Google slammed the site it simply used up all the connections and shut it down.